# Wiring a single phase 120/240VAC motor with 8 wires

Tags: motor, wiring, single-phase

We have a submersible motor. It is a 2HP, single phase, 120/240 dual voltage motor. This motor has 8 wires. U1, U2, U5, V1, V2, V5, Blue(not numbered) and Red(not numbered). How do i wire this motor? 
I tried multiple options but that ended up tripping the feeder. Cannot find anything online that could help either. I also want to add run capacitor to the system?

Comment: Does the motor shaft freely spin?

Comment: Blue and red might be a thermal switch or sensor. Measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZbkXU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should determine x,y,z positions with ohmmeter. The red and blue could be something else, for example the electromechanical brake.  Or maybe the centrifugal switch, for use with starting capacitor.

Then you wire the capacitor, for 220V example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAjiF.png)</sup>